# How to make my program wait until a task is finished before continuing?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I need the Url/Uri of a image on firebase, to then be used on the next line. It looks something like this:

```
Uri uri = storageReference.getDownloadUrl().getResult();
this.doAThing(uri);
```

The problem is I get an error saying "Task is not yet complete". How do I get it to just wait until the task finishes/Is there a better way to get the Uri?

Comment: If i remember correctly, `getDownloadUrl()` is deprecated, you should use a `Task` with `then` and/or `onComplete` instead.

Comment: please share java version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I required some similar concept in my project. I had to use a inbuilt firebase listener to get the URL.

> I used an **getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener()**, this returned an URI

Here's a part of my code snippet :

```
filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        Log.d("=== link ",uri.toString());

        // Your code
    }
});
```

> filepath - it is an StorageReference Object referenced to that file.

Hope this helps.